# Can a BottomSheet be shown behind another view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is it possible to open a `BottomSheet` behind another view? (In my case a button)
What kind of layout should I use for that?

[image]

Comment: I think that you should use CoordinatorLayout or FrameLayout for this behavior. But I have not tested it...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with a layout like this one, which worked in my case:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/viewYouWantAbove"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So the view you want to be above the bottom sheet simply needs to be after the bottom sheet in the xml.

**Note**: If your bottom sheet has an elevation, the other view must have a superior or equal elevation to be above.